# Are all queues, priority queues? If not, what is the difference?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

Just beginning my journey of learning data structures and algorithms, and I'm getting hung up on the fact that there is information everywhere about this kind of stuff with different nicknames for each data structure. But in layman's terms are all queues in fact priority queues, the priority bit being exactly what makes them so special?

I tried googling are all queues priority queues and I got recommended to stack overflow's massive hive mind of information.

Comment: No, not all queues are priority queues. Regular queues are first-in-first-out structures: the order of insertion is the order of retrieval. Priority queues are based on priority: as items are inserted, whatever is currently the most important will be retrieved first.

Comment: No. A queue is "first in, first out" (FIFO) data structure. A priority queue is "whenever in, the highest priority out first".

Comment: @SergioTulentsev *In laymans terms* a FIFO queue is merely a priority queue ordered by insertion time.  The confusion is the mix of "laymans terms" vs "data structures"

Comment: @MooingDuck: while in theory you are correct, I think that in practice this generalization is counter-productive for beginners.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Normally I'd agree, but I think this counter productive generalization is **exactly** what the question is about

Comment: @MooingDuck: it appears so. Anyway, good answer :+1:

Comment: The term "queue" itself is pretty vague, it means "something that resembles a waiting queue in the common meaning of the term". But the two most-common data structures called queue are by far the First-In-First-Out queue and the priority queue.

Comment: @Stef "First-In-First-Out" is not a data structure, it's a type of queue. It can be efficiently *implemented* via any of a long list of data structures.  Similarly, a priority queue can be efficiently implemented via any of a short list of data structures.

Comment: @MooingDuck I agree with your statement that a FIFO queue is a type of queue. I disagree with your statement that a FIFO queue is not a data structure. Note that the term "data structure" can refer to many levels of abstraction. A very abstract data structure can be implemented using a less-abstract data structure, which can itself be implemented using an even-less-abstract data structure, etc. Anyway, the point of my comment was to answer the OP's question, not to engage in a debate. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is both Yes and No.  *Theoretically*, all queues are priority queues, yes. But if the priority is insertion order (Aka First-In-First-Out), then it can be implemented with other specifically optimized *data structures*, which may be faster.

A generic priority queue requires a somewhat complex "heap" sort of data structure, which `std::queue` or `std::heap` handle.

However, an insertion-order-queue can be implemented via a "list-like" data structure, which is often *far* faster, such as `std::list` and `std::dequeue`.  So while they are the same general *concept*, specific implementations often usually use totally unrelated *data structures*.  (One can theoretically also use `std::vector`, but it requires a little work to avoid O(n) `pop()`, so usually people don't use that.)

You see this in other places too.  In layman's term, a "list" is a general concept. But C++ calls this concept "SequenceContainer", and then very confusingly named their SequenceContainer linked list data structure `std::list`. But in layman's terms, `std::vector` and `std::deque` and `std::array` are also lists, despite being totally unrelated data structures.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that, so with data structures I could modify them then yeah? Like adding a memory block as a pointer to create a linked array or linked priority queue/queue.

Comment: @KravenBranson: depends on the data structure. You cant insert or delete from a `std::array`, or a `const` structure.

Comment: Did you mean that linked lists are faster for regular queues? This would heavily depend on the situation, but is probably not true in most situations. See the "access memory less" section of this classic by Bjarne Stroustrup: https://www.stroustrup.com/Software-for-infrastructure.pdf.

Comment: @Julian: No, I mean that a insertion-order-queue can be implemented via a SequenceContainer, virtually all of which are *far* faster than a heap for push_back and pop_front.  Actually, in this specific case, a `std::list` is quite performant, though still slower than a `std::dequeue`.  A naive ordered `std::vector` is slower than a heap in this specific case, though it wouldn't be hard to make a similar data structure that's on par with the other SequenceContainers.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Question: "Are all queues priority queues?" Answer: "They are the same theoretical concept, but are implemented with completely unrelated data structures." Who's "they"? All queues?

Comment: Yes. Insomuch as there *is* a distinction, one is a superset of the other as a theoretical concept, but there can be multiple data structures. I've reworded that sentence, hopefully bringing clarity. Actually, I've now reworded a lot of the answer.

Comment: It's also interesting to note that what we call a stack can be thought of as a priority queue where the priority is essentially, "reverse insertion order." Both it and, as you noted, the FIFO queue, are special cases of a priority queue, and can be implemented more efficiently because the ordering is implicit in the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

"Queue" is both a name for a general group of data structures and for a particular datastructure within that group.

As a general group, you can think of a queue just as you would think about queueing people or items: an ordered series of things, where the order determines which item is taken out first.

Particular datastructures within the group differ by the way in which that order is maintained. The particular datastructures that go by just "queue" add all new items at one end of the queue and extracts them at the other. It is "first in, first out" (FIFO), just like people queueing at a museum or grocery items queued on a conveyor belt at the supermarket.

The particular datastructures that go by "priority queue" order items by their "value", whatever that might mean. For example, I might priority-queue people so I can always call the tallest one first. Implementations differ, among other things, by whether the entire queue is kept sorted by this value, or it is only cleverly arranged so that the greatest or least item is always easy to find. Those are the max-heap and the min-heap, respectively.

To conclude, strictly speaking not all queues are priority queues, although Mooing Duck is right that all queues are somehow ordered.